# Compressing Iplimage to jpeg on memory

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am working on a project that I will transfer webcam images on the network , real time. But Iplimage has a big size so it does not fit in a udp packet. I have to compress it to jpeg format. I made some research many examples do save the picture on disk then read to the memory. But I want do it on memory. I am using Qt on my project.

Is there any solution for compressing Iplimage on memory ? 
May be Qt has a solution for that ?

Comment: Are you lucky enough that [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) understands your format? I didn't see "Iplimage" on the list, but it's hard to fathom an image type missing from ImageMagick.

Comment: Anyway the compressed image should be split across several UDP packets. I doubt that a jpeg compressed image will fit in just one UDP packet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt has [QImageWriter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimagewriter.html) class which supports JPEG format and allows specifying compression level. You can use it to save QImage data to [QByteArray](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qbytearray.html). Below is an example:

```
QImage image("/home/image_from.png");

QByteArray array;
QBuffer buffer(&array);

// write image to memory buffer
QImageWriter writer;
writer.setDevice(&buffer);
writer.setFormat("JPEG");
writer.setCompression(9);
writer.write(image);
```

or you can use [QPixmap](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpixmap.html) save method; it also allows specifying memory buffer as output device:

```
QImage image("/home/image_from.png");
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image);

QByteArray array;
QBuffer buffer(&array);
pixmap.save(&buffer, "JPEG", 9);
```

hope this helps, regards

Answer (score 0):

Or since you are using openCV iplimage) you can just use [imencode](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-imencode) to convert to jpeg in a buffer

Comment: is it available in javaCV ?