# Pixmap screenshot convert to low-quality

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

i'm using qt creator to create sample Remote Assistance
my project have 2 part server and client
the client taking screenshot and send it to server but screenshot pictures have to much quality and it take too much size and is not good idea to send it from local area network or internet protocol 
i need to resize image size or convert it to low quality so that can be almost Recognizable

this is my screenshot codes

```
 void MainWindow::shootScreen()
 {
 originalPixmap = QPixmap(); // clear image for low memory situations
                             // on embedded devices.
 originalPixmap = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->grabWindow(0);

 //emit getScreen(originalPixmap);

 updateScreenshotLabel();


 }

 void MainWindow::updateScreenshotLabel()
 {
 this->ui->label_2->setPixmap(originalPixmap.scaled(this->ui->label_2-    >size(),
                                                  Qt::KeepAspectRatio,
                                                  Qt::SmoothTransformation));
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you know how to change an image size, why isn't that enough?

Just do:

```
QPixmap smallPixmap = originalPixmap.scaled( QSize( originalPixmap.size().x()/4, originalPixmap.size().y()/4 ), Qt::KeepAspectRatio,                                                   Qt::SmoothTransformation );
```

And send `smallPixmap` instead of `originalPixmap`.

You could (should) also compress the image using [QImageWriter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagewriter.html), this will allow you to create an image compressed with jpeg format, which should also reduce the memory usage.

[Check this](http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/showQtExample.php?index=575&key=QImageWriterQTcpSocketSend), looks like they do what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you but can you tell me how i can to compress originalPixmap with QImageWrite?

Comment: Check the links provided. First convert it to a `QImage` (`QPixmap::toImage()`) then use `QImageWriter` as proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5443085/3336423